# internet explorer export favorities in CMD

Tags: windows, cmd, internet-explorer-10

How I can export favorites IE 10 through **command line**?
I already tried to find any ready to use tools, but it doesn't works...

It is possible to do?

Comment: Windows Scripting Host would probably be a good tool.  But you'll probably have to write the utility yourself.

Comment: Do you have a bunch of `.URL` files in your favorites folder and you want to put them into a single text file with just the internet addresses?

Answer (score 2):

Best way would probably to mirror or copy out the entire folder favorties with Robocopy. 
Windows Vista and newer path = c:\Users[user name]\favorites\
Windows XP and older path = c:\documents and settings[user name]\favorites\